# Time and distance calculations Google maps routing

Tags: google-maps, optimization

We have run into a wall with our app. We need the ability to take a static stop list and calculate the total working time and total distance of this list. At the same time we also need the option to optimize this list and compare it to the static list to give a comparison of total working time and total distance between static and optimized.

The service we are using for the route optimization works great. It optimizes using Google Maps and gives us the total working time and total distance for the optimized list. Our issue arises when we try to get the working time and distance for the static stop list. The route optimization tool does not allow us to "lock" the stop order, which we could feed the static list and get the working time and distance. So, instead we are using a workaround by using the Cloudmade routing api (which uses Openstreetmaps) to calculate this information for the static.

This is our primary issue - when we originally bring the stops into our system we geocode them using Google maps to ensure our route optimization software has accurate waypoints for optimization. When we pass these stops to Cloudmade/Openstreetmaps it is often not finding the stops and errors out before calculating the working time and distance. It seems OSM is not the most reliable solution.

Does anyone know of a solution similar to the Cloudmade routing api http://cloudmade.com/products/routing that uses Google maps instead? Or does Google offer an api directly that can accomplish this?

Hope this makes sense. Thanks

Comment: What does your code look like?  What is the problem?  Is the directions API "optimizing" the order of the waypoints?

Comment: The problem primarily is OSM does not have as much data as Google Maps, so although Google can geocode it, when those coordinates are passed to OSM it can't find the route between points. I am using a service called Viamente to optimize the order. We are only using Cloudmade to calculate total working time and distance. Can the Google directions api accomplish the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the gebweb tsp solver. It uses the Google directions api. It also tries to reduce the query traffic by using a distance matrix and the maximum of waypoints.

Answer (score -1):

Okay, I'm blind. I found the Google Distance Matrix API that accomplishes exactly what I'm looking for. For some reason I missed it earlier. Too bad Google Maps for biz is $10K a year...